# How can I compare fonts not on my computer?

Tags: fonts

What is a service where I can perform side by side comparison of all fonts? Not just fonts on my computer, as most services seem to offer.

Answer (score 2):

[Myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com) is my usual go-to resource. They have an extremely broad library, a good system for type specimens, and a lightbox feature for tossing sets together.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I can't vote you up because I don't have 15 reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think it's not going to be possible to get one site that lists *all* fonts ever created but services like fontdeck.com, typekit.com, fontsquirrel.com, etc. often have ways to compare and contrast all the fonts that are available on their sites.  All three of the examples I just listed *do* have quite a few fonts available as well so hopefully that'll be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I can't vote you up because I don't have 15 reputation yet. IThe sites above don't appear to be able to compare standard non-sellable fonts only ones they can sell. For instance Lucida Grande wouldn't come up. This would be a niche product if a developer is looking for ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that [Typecast](http://typecast.com/) is now out of private beta. It's a very slick tool for testing webfonts on screen -- testing them in your favorite layout app is a waste of time.